# how to write directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have below html code

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'photos', '{{ destination.id || 'home' | lowercase }}', 'click']);">
```

if destination.id is not available I need to get expression value as home. but when I place 'home' in single quote its breaking layout in IE8 and gives error

what would be the best possible way to achieve this or any other method

Comment: Escape the single quotes? It's breaking because it thinks you're ending the statement there.

Comment: Thanks for reply. When I use as destination.id || home in browser its rendering as ' ' blank space